# making background image "grow" from bottom left when sizing window

Tags: html, css, image

This is a little tricky to explain what is happening.

http://easyuniv.com/staging/gonzaga/

If you go to my site above, you can see how the background image moves around when the window is shrunk and expanded horizontally. I am hoping to make it so that the bottom left corner of the image is fixed in the bottom left corner of the window regardless of the window size, and then if it is wider, it will show more of the image. How can i accomplish this? I have tried a lot of different variations of settings

Comment: You have several typo in your `style.css`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your background position to `left bottom`:

```css
html {
    background-position: left bottom;
}
```

---

Alternatively, just use the shorthand property to combine it with your `background-image` statement:

```css
html {
    background: url("img/background_image.png") no-repeat left bottom;
}
```

Comment: this is perfect, thank you! i also had to make the height of html 100%, which is what i didn't realize earlier.